Highlight on click in ggplotly
In my chart, I want to highlight the point that has been clicked on. Minimal example:
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot2::ggplot(iris, 
    ggplot2::aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, size=Petal.Length, text=Species)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point(alpha = 0.2, fill="lightgray", colour="black", pch=21) + 
    ggplot2::scale_size_area(max_size=20, breaks=seq(0,1, length.out=5)) 
 
gp <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
gp$x$config$displayModeBar <- FALSE
gp

This works, but no highlighting yet. I tried:
gp <- plotly::highlight(gp, on="plotly_click", color="darkred")
gp

but this does not produce the desired behaviour. What am I doing wrong?

Seems like all I was missing was highlight_key, i.e.
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(plotly::highlight_key(iris), ...

and it works as expected.
